# Copying attributes to InterfaceInterceptor generated proxy

Tags: c#, unity-container, reflection.emit, unity-interception

Suppose I have an interface exposed over WCF:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Foo();
}
```

And an implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(...)]
class Service : IService
{
    public void Foo() { /* impl */ }
}
```

I can publish `Service` over WCF and everything works well.

Now, I want to use Unity to perform interception of `Service`. I can use WCF behaviors for that, but `IService` (and `Service` that implements it) are sometimes accessed by internal services and not over WCF, and I want an interception mechanism that will apply both when the class is accessed over WCF and when it's accessed locally.

I can use Unity's `InterfaceInterceptor` for this, but then the proxy that I get will not have the `ServiceBehavior` attribute, which obviously affects the WCF behavior and is therefore needed.

Now, I can use `TransparentProxyInterceptor` or `VirtualMethodInterceptor`, which will inherit from my `Service` class (and thus inherit the attributes?), but the `InterfaceInterceptor` seems like the "right" interceptor to use in this case. I'm working with interfaces here, after all.

Looking at Unity's code, it seems that `InterfaceInterceptor` uses `Reflection.Emit` to generate the proxy. If only it used `TypeBuilder.SetCustomAttributes`, it could simply copy the attributes from my original type and apply them to its proxy. I couldn't find a Unity extension point to do this, though. The closest I got was the `InterfaceInterceptorClassGenerator`, but it too does not expose its `TypeBuilder`.

Is there a simple way to extend the `InterfaceInterceptor` to copy attributes from the underlying implementation? Is there another way to get the `ServiceBehavior` specified on `Service` to apply to the proxy?

Comment: ...when your service class is accessed internally, does it throw exceptions or faults on failure?

Comment: @sq33G it throws exceptions. We have behaviors that translate those to faults.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a new layer for your scenario as follows,

[image: add a new layer]

You can do any interception to "ServiceImp" that implement IServiceImp. Service do not have any function code but just a warpper and used as a Service **ONLY**, **Do NOT** do any interception to Service, Service has a dependency on ServiceImp(or IServiceImp which can be injected by Unity).

Now your local can use Service or ServiceImp. and WCF InstanceProvider can use resovled Service which still has ServiceBehavior attribute.

Comment: This will certainly work, but it forces me to write some plumbing code which will have to be maintained. E.g. whenever I add a method, I need to add it to 2 interfaces + 2 classes. I was hoping to get Unity to do the heavy-lifting for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF, then I don't see why you wouldn't have an endpoint that you use internally.

Instead of using a network transport, for example, you'd use a named-pipe transport.

The risk in using *another* interception framework (whether it's Unity or another) is that you aren't guaranteed that you are maintaining parity in the interception implementations.

That said, you are better off just using WCF internally as well, along with a channel that suits your needs in that scenario.

Note that you can write your own transport (perhaps using shared memory, or something of the sort) which is more efficient when making calls in the same app domain (assuming you've determined that the transport *actually is a problem*).

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I hadn't really thought of WCF as an interception framework. Up until now it has served us as a commuication framework. True, we do have behaviors in place, but they are only there to help with the communication side of things (e.g. translate exceptions to faults). We want to use Unity's interception to apply business logic (e.g. authorization issues, transactions, etc.).

Comment: @telewin: Then perhaps you should think of it the other way around; on the client side, use Unity to get the proxies, and when you don't need the client, use Unity to get the actual instances.  In this case, I'd still advocate using WCF to get all instances; if you want to get them through Unity to have uniformity in all usage scenarios (always get a WCF proxy through Unity), even better, IMO.